# Technique to reduce dense point cloud in 3D

Tags: point-clouds

I have a point cloud consist of more than 100,000 points , i have to reduce this dense point cloud.

My point cloud is sorted with respect to z axis.

I used simple mathematics like, if selected point's x=3 , y = 4 , z = 5 . Then compare with remaining point cloud with this criteria (x - x(i) == 0.0001f ) if matches , then try another one till end of the point cloud , and select the most updated one , by this way i am reducing the point cloud. It provides me results , but not up to my expectations.

SO is there any technique to reduce dense point cloud..

Answer (score 0):

I should be writing this as a comment but dont have enough rep. 
You can do a singular value decomposition. Take your big long vector `X`and do [SVD](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.svd.html) decomposition on it. Plot your singular values obtained and see which of the singular values have a high weight, select those this will get you the optimal rank `r` of the matrix. So you will reconstruct your original `X` matrix as `X' = U Sig V` where each of these are rank `r` truncated.

Comment: You have any example.?

Comment: just googled it, check out this link [here](http://ethen8181.github.io/machine-learning/dim_reduct/svd.html)

Comment: I have to reduce the point cloud ......look this file https://file.io/luo5KH
and look at this file :- https://file.io/MgIGAR

Comment: cant view the files. do you have a 3d matrix ? to reduce this you probably need something like high order SVD.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/shalinsirwani/6741fe44825d25a627540f33d4fb4386 
This is my desired output file

Comment: Please let me know if I understand what you want to do. You have a big array of shape `m x n`where `m`is a huge number (40620 i guess ?). You want your final array to be of shape `k x n`where k is a small number (around 1400) ?

Comment: No no i don't have any grid of m x n . i have 3 dimensional point coordinate collection which are forming some shape . And now i have to remove some of points without loosing the shape of point cloud

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193023/discussion-between-siddhant-tandon-and-sha111).